# React Redux: Getting Props And Updating State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying out React/Redux/JS for the first time.  I am a little confused about setting state in component vs letting redux update it.

I want to click a button to set the lightOn to true and have the updated this.props.lightOn value display.  I am missing something fundamental but not sure what.

action:

```
export const setLight = lightStatus => dispatch => {
  const res = lightStatus;
  console.log(res); // => true on click

  dispatch({ type: SET_LIGHT, payload: res });
};
```

In the component, {this.props.onLight} is undefined so I am not updating state correctly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//import * as actions from '../actions';
import { setLight } from '../actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Light extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        Light Status: {this.props.lightOn}
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => this.props.setLight(true)}
        >
          Set Light!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    lightOn: state.lightOn
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  //whenever selectBook is called the result should be passed to all of our reducers
  return bindActionCreators({ setLight: setLight }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Light);
```

the reducer (updated with spread operator):

```
import { SET_LIGHT } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LIGHT:
     return { ...state, lightOn: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting state with array I am now setting with object.  I guess I was putting lightOn object in light array which was making it inaccessible.

action:

```
export const setLight = lightStatus => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: SET_LIGHT, payload: lightStatus });
};
```

reducer:

```
import { SET_LIGHT } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = { on: false }, action) {
  console.log('state ', state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LIGHT:
      return { ...state, on: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//import * as actions from '../actions';
import { setLight } from '../actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Light extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Light On: {this.props.light.on.toString()}
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => this.props.setLight(!this.props.light.on)}
        >
          Set Light!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { light: state.light };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ setLight: setLight }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Light);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about set it as a state instead of pass direct to the function ? First binding it inside Constructor and then on click setState to true ?

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state:{lightOn: false};
this.OnClick = this.OnClick.bind(this);
}

onClick(event) {
this.setState({lightOn: true});
}

onClick ={this.onClick()}
```

As you are using redux , you can do it this way by returning a fresh state instead

```
   return {...state, action.payload };
```

Comment: what ? Hes using redux. Hes not looking for a internal state way of handling this...

Answer (score 2):

How it works?
Through `connect` you can inject props that are used to control redux state and bind it to the component. For example:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.sendSomething('someName');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.stateProp}</div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state = ({
    stateProp: state.someReduxState,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    sendSomething: (name) => dispatch(someActionCreator(name)),
});

const ConnectedComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(SomeComponent);
```

In given example you are binding `someReduxState` part of state to `stateProp`, which is injected into component. You are injecting method (`sendSomething`) that will dispatch and action in redux. If component relays on displaying part of redux state, it will be updated each time redux state changes, because props that are injected to component will change. You can find more in official Redux documentation [here](http://redux.js.org/), or you can watch free tutorial on egghead [here](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux).

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a new state here

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LIGHT:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You're directly returning `action.payload` which is simply `lightStatus`

Which means you can't access `state.lightOn` in your `mapStateToProps`

Your should be doing

```
 case SET_LIGHT:
              return {
                ...state,
                lightOn: action.payload,
              };
```

Or directly

```
case SET_LIGHT:
                  return {
                    ...state,
                    action.payload,
                  };
```

This way the entire state is not lost and its not directly mutating the state.
Here i am using the [object spread operator](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html#using-object-spread-operator) instead of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for the sake of simpicity.

Comment: I have added the spread operator in my reducer like so: return { ...state, lightOn: action.payload }  but I still do not get a value for this.props.lightOn in component

Answer (score 1):

the wrong on the reducer, the reducer should return the state object with lightOn key, but you return payload value, and this is the issue.
your reducer should return lightOn with payload value like this.

```
import { SET_LIGHT } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LIGHT:
      return {...state, action.payload}
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```