# VS Default Bootstrapped React/Redux app: connect navMenu to redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have created a new React/Redux app from the default Visual Studio Template and now I want to connect the NavMenu component to the redux store, but unfortunately, after adding the NavBar-connection to the store

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.applicationUser,
    ApplicationUser.actionCreators
)(NavMenu) as typeof NavMenu;
```

the Layout component

```
export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

now complains

> Error TS2604  (TS) JSX element type 'NavMenu' does not have any construct or call signatures.

and as I am new to react / redux even after googeling around I can't find an answer to this problem, although this might be an easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you messed up you NavMenu connect. I answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115233/react-redux-getting-props-and-updating-state/47115389#47115389). First of all, `connect` is a generic function and you need to use it like this:

```
const ConnectedComponent = connnect<StateProps, DispatchProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(MyComponent);
```

Additionally your mapping functions should look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): StateProps => ({
  foo: state.bar,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<ActionType>): DispatchProps => ({
  addFoo: (name: string) => dispatch(addFoo(name)),
});
```

Hope this helps.